# not able to pass array in chart js with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chart.js

I have some trouble when trying to display dynamically  fetched data in my bar chart using chartjs , the passed array variable can't display properly the data and keep showing nothing
[image]

I tried by manually entering all the enteries in labels and data and it works. Can anyone suggest how to pass the array data properly?
Any ideas how to solve these?

**Here is my JS code **

```
const ctxOne = document.querySelector('#myChartOne');
let categoryName = new Array();
$.ajax({
   url : "../controllers/getCategoryNames.php",
   method :"GET",
   success: function(data){
      let categoryData = JSON.parse(data);
      for(let i in categoryData){
         categoryName.push(categoryData[i].category_name);
      }
     
   }

})
// get the budget percent used for this month
var usedBudgetTmonth = new Array();
var usedBudgetLmonth = new Array();
$.ajax({
   url : "../controllers/budgetUsedTmonth.php",
   method :"GET",
   success: function(data){
      let budgetData = JSON.parse(data);
      categoryName.map((elt)=>{
         for(let i in budgetData){
            if(budgetData[i].category_name === elt){
               usedBudgetTmonth.push(budgetData[i].pct)
            }else{
               usedBudgetTmonth.push(0);
            }
         }
      })    
   }

})
// last month
$.ajax({
   url : "../controllers/budgetUsedLmonth.php",
   method :"GET",
   success: function(data){
      let budgetData = JSON.parse(data);
      categoryName.map((elt)=>{
         for(let i in budgetData){
            if(budgetData[i].category_name === elt){
               usedBudgetLmonth.push(budgetData[i].pct)
            }else{
               usedBudgetLmonth.push(0);
            }
            
         }
      })    
   }

})
var chartData = {
   labels : categoryName,
   datasets : [
      {
      label: 'This Month',
      data: usedBudgetTmonth,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      borderColor:  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1
  }, 
  {
   label: 'Last Month',
   data: usedBudgetLmonth,
   backgroundColor:'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
   borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
   borderWidth: 1
}]
}

const myChartOne = new Chart(ctxOne, {
   type: 'bar',
   data : chartData
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using async code but expecting it to work like sync code. When you call `new Chart` all the arrays are still empty. So you will need to adjust the chart directly in your ajax and not the original variables or create the chart in your ajax

```js
$.ajax({
   url : "../controllers/getCategoryNames.php",
   method :"GET",
   success: function(data){
      let categoryData = JSON.parse(data);
      for(let i in categoryData){
         myChartOne.data.labels.push(categoryData[i].category_name);
      }
      myChartOne.update();
   }
})
```

Comment: can I use async:false instead ?, thank you so much btw

Comment: Never use `async: false`. That will result in code that blocks your UI which is very bad for the user. Instead learn how to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and then [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to harnass the power of asynchronicity.